# Join multiple columns of one table to single column of another table in single query

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

This is my query

```
select u.FirstName as AssignedBy, u1.FirstName as RespondedBy, u2.FirstName as ClosedBy
from Messages M
left join User u on isnull(M.AssignedBy, 0) = u.UserId    
left join User u1 on isnull(M.RespondedBy, 0) = u1.UserId
left join User u2 on isnull(M.closedby, 0) = u2.UserId
```

Is it possible to write the join in a single query? I want to improve performance of my query and so I don't want to make 3 joins so trying it in a single join as my User table has lots of records so. I have all the indexes on both the tables. I tried

```
select u.FirstName as AssignedBy, u.FirstName as RespondedBy, u.FirstName as ClosedBy
from Messages M
left join User u on 
(isnull(M.AssignedBy, 0) = u.UserId or isnull(M.RespondedBy, 0) = u.UserId or isnull(M.closedby, 0) = u.UserId)
```

But this query gives incorrect output as I have many rows which has records in all the three join columns. Is there any other way to achieve the same?

Comment: How bad is your performance?  Can you edit your question with the execution plan for the query?

Answer (score 1):

Your original query looks fine.  If you have an index on `User(UserId)` or better yet `User(UserId, FirstName)` then I would think the performance would be fine.

Using `or` in `join` conditions is generally going to make the performance worse rather than better.

Your issue may simple be the size of the `Messages` table.  It can take a while to return very large result sets.

Comment: yes Gordon, my table indeed is very large but I cant help it so trying to optimize other queries. I have index on UserId.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a 'better' way to do this. The only thing I would advice against is the `ISNULL()` construction in the `JOIN` as it doesn't really serve any purpose but might confuse the optimizer. 
The query as it is does "require" you have a proper index on the User table but I'm assuming the `UserId` field already is the PK of said table...

```
select u.FirstName as AssignedBy, 
       u1.FirstName as RespondedBy, 
       u2.FirstName as ClosedBy
from Messages M
left join User u on M.AssignedBy = u.UserId    
left join User u1 on M.RespondedBy = u1.UserId
left join User u2 on M.closedby = u2.UserId
```

How bad is performance anyway? And are you sure the link to the User table is the culprit? (I'm guessing you're also limiting the results of the query by having other predicates on the Messages table; e.g. by only wanting the open messages, or the last 100 messages etc...)

(a query plan might be interesting)

Comment: I am not sure User table is the culprit coz there is lot of data in Messages table. I have limited the results of the query, also there are many where conditions which filter the results, but I want to know can i specify this part of the query?

Comment: In that case I'd simply focus on 'the other' conditions first; the (triple) join to the User table looks OK as it is IMHO. Like I said, have a look at the Query Execution Plan and see where the 'heavy' parts are.